# Understanding JMP Codes in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, opcode, instruction-encoding

Iv'e just recently scratched the surface of assembly language and debugging. I have the following code:

```
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
006E3689   .  E8 C5F9FFFF   CALL 006E3053
->006E368E      E9            DB E9
->006E368F      35            DB 35                                    ; CHAR '5'
->006E3690      80            DB 80
->006E3691   .  0000D490      DD 90D40000
006E3695  />  E8 72040000   CALL 006E3B0C
```

And further down...

```
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
006EB6C8  /.  6A 58         PUSH 58
006EB6CA  |.  68 A0372A00   PUSH 2A37A0
006EB6CF    ^ E9 C17FFFFF   JMP 006E3695
```

Now before I compiled the codes indicted by -> were actually all included in a `JMP 006EB6C8` which of course just jumped down to the second set of code, pushed a couple things and returned back to the top.

Now this code is still functional but I am unsure why the code changed(using Ollydbg) when I compiled, but more importantly(I believe) is how the code knows to jump and how far. My research so far has told me `E9` is a opcode for jump, but Iv'e haven't been able to find information on `35` and `80`.

I'm assuming the `0000D490` is some sort of offset, but I cant find any math that adds up the the `006EB6C8` address.

Comment: You don't need to guess what an opcode does, download the manual: [Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html). http://ref.x86asm.net/ is a useful website. [udis86 disassembler](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/) has a nice disassembler called `udcli`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470900/disassembling-file-that-contain-big-data-or-is-compressed

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921735/asm-write-a-jump-command-to-a-x86-64-binary-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am puzzled why OllyDbg doesn't disassemble that jump for you. Anyway, `E9` is a jmp near, as you have figured out. It takes a 4 byte offset from the start of the next instruction. As such, your instruction is actually `E9 35 80 00 00` which means `jump to address of next instruction + 00008035` (x86 uses little endian byte order). The address of the next instruction is of course `006E3693`, so the jump takes you to `006E3693 + 00008035 = 006EB6C8` which is what you have originally written.